# Plotting in a frame of a GUI in R

Tags: r

I have this GUI with three frames, in first one I  put the buttons and  second is for plotting. The problem I am facing is I could not plot my  graph inside this frame1:

```
library(gWidgets2)
library(gWidgetsRGtk2)
library(RGtk2)
options(guiToolkit="RGtk2")
win=gwindow("FUZZY   TRADING   MODEL  ")
img <- gdkPixbufNewFromFile("E:/clusterring/str.1.png")
getToolkitWidget(win)$setIcon(img$retval)
paned<-gpanedgroup(cont=win)
group<- ggroup ( cont = paned , horizontal = FALSE )
getBlock(win)$modifyBg(GtkStateType["normal"], "purple")
frame <- gframe ( "RESULT:" , cont = paned , horizontal = TRUE)
tbl=glayout(cont=frame)
size(tbl)<-c(700,700)
tbl[8,10] =  gfilebrowse (text = "Select file...", type = "open", quote = FALSE,
                         filter = list("Text File" = list(patterns = c("*.csv"))),      
                         container = tbl)
tbl[13,10]= gbutton("GENERATING BUY AND SELL  SIGNALS ",cont=tbl,handler=function(h,...) generate_buy_sell-signal())
tbl[18,6] =glabel("ENTER PROFIT TARGET:-")
tbl[18,10] =gedit("", container=tbl,coerce.with=as.numeric) 
tbl[22,6] =glabel("STOP LOSS TARGET:-")
tbl[22,10] =gedit("", container=tbl,coerce.with=as.numeric) 
tbl[25,2]=gbutton("RUN BACK TEST  ",cont=tbl)
tbl[28,2]<-plut<<-gbutton("PLOT GRAPH ",cont=tbl)
tbl[25,10]=gbutton("GENERATING BACKTEST SUMMARY ",cont=tbl)
tbl[28,10]= gbutton("CLEAR",cont=tbl)
tbl[1,2]=img <- gimage("E:/clusterring/pr.1.png")

------------------------------------frame to enter the plot-----------------------------
frame1 <- gframe ( "PLOT:" , cont = group, horizontal = TRUE,expand=TRUE)
---------------------------------------XXX-------------------------------------------

size(frame1)<-c(400,300)
frame2<- gframe ( "BACKTESTING SUMMARY:" , cont = group, horizontal = TRUE,expand=TRUE)
size(frame2)<-c(400,300)
tbl1=glayout(cont=frame2)
tbl1[2,2] =glabel("ENTER PROFIT TARGET(T):-")
tbl1[2,7]= gedit("", container=tbl1,coerce.with=as.numeric)
tbl1[4,2] =glabel("NO OF BUY TRADES:-")
tbl1[4,7]= gedit("", container=tbl1,coerce.with=as.numeric)
tbl1[6,2] =glabel("NO OF SELL TRADES:-")
tbl1[6,7]= gedit("", container=tbl1,coerce.with=as.numeric)
tbl1[8,2] =glabel("TOTAL WINING TRADES(WT):-")
tbl1[8,7]= gedit("", container=tbl1,coerce.with=as.numeric)
tbl1[12,2] =glabel("% OF WINING TRADE :-")
tbl1[12,7]= gedit("", container=tbl1,coerce.with=as.numeric)
tbl1[14,2] =glabel("% OF LOOSING TRADE :-")
tbl1[14,7]= gedit("", container=tbl1,coerce.with=as.numeric)
tbl1[16,2] =glabel("PROFIT:-")
tbl1[16,7]= gedit("", container=tbl1,coerce.with=as.numeric)


---------------------------------my plot -----------------------------------------

**addHandlerClicked(plut,handler=function(h,...)
{ 
 all<- plot(Close , type='l',xlab="CLOSED PRICES", ylab="TIME")
 matplot(buy_Pos,price_signal_allign[buy_Pos,2],col=c("green"),add=T)
 matplot(sell_pos,price_signal_allign[sell_pos,2],col=c("yellow"),add=T)
 matplot(sell_pt_pos,price_signal_allign[sell_pt_pos,2],col=c("purple"),add=T)
 matplot(sell_st_pos,price_signal_allign[sell_st_pos,2],col=c("blue"),add=T)
 matplot(buy_st_pos,price_signal_allign[buy_st_pos,2],col=c("violet"),add=T)
 matplot(buy_pt_pos,price_signal_allign[buy_pt_pos,2],col=c("brown"),add=T)
 add(frame1,group,all,expand=TRUE)
})
```

Comment: I'm looking for a `ggraphics` widget to hold the plot and don't see it. Might be as simple as adding that to the "Plot" frame.

Comment: I wanted to add: you only need `library(gWidgets2);options(guiToolkit="RGtk2")` (1st and 4th lines). Adding the 2nd line is completely unnecessary (and in your case loads the wrong thing as it has no middle "2") and the 3rd line only needed if you want access to the underlying `RGtk2` API.

Comment: ya dude I  had added  the  ggraphics  widget into   my code  in R Studio ,but it showed frame is too large  ,then  i had tried in  R ,it worked just fine , RStudio got some  bucks ,thats why  i could not solve the issue ,now its done ....,ggraphics code is missing from  this code  i had given ...........i was unknown  of this widget  earlier ..............

Comment: Rigth  @jverzani   i  dont  think  those will cause some  serious problems ...............,like to  hear  your advice................

Comment: Its been a pleasure talking to  u @jverzani , can u suggest about alignment  of  the  frames  in an  GUI  ..............hardly get it right ...............

Comment: I'd start by sizing the parent window, not the `glayout` instance. Then when packing in widgets, they should expand to accommodate the child widgets. For packing childen `anchor` is the argument to adjust.

Comment: Sir , is there  any course structure  to enroll  for, in  statics using R  while  i  m working...................., i would  like to have your advice ...........please reply .

Comment: one more thing I want to  ask ............how to return a value from a function and use it  in another function............@jverzani

Comment: statistics.com has several online offerings in R. RStudio offers training sessions, but less frequently. There are a few others. Some may come to you if you happen to live in the right area.

Comment: composing two functions in R is quite simple, just make sure the return value of one matches the inputs of the other. There are loads of tips here http://adv-r.had.co.nz/ though that might be too advanced when starting out. If you are talking about composing event handlers, that is a much different thing as these are called asynchronously and not in a pipeline.

Comment: Yes sir  you  are right ..............,  i  have  a  buton function like   
BSS<-function(h,...)
  
  { 
    
  signal_fuzzy
  }                                                               ,  i want  to   call  it  in  another button   function  called   RBS<-function(h,...)
  
{ 
   data1<-cbind(ashdata$Close, signal_fuzzy)     
  }                                                                         can  you  help  me to   call the   signal_fuzzy  inside  this another  function (RBS).  i  m struggling  with this very  much  Sir  your  help  your  will  be  very  helpful  sir.

Comment: In `gWidgets2` you can invoke the change handler on a button via `btn$invoke_change_handler()`. If you make this call in the handler for button 2, it will invoke the handler of button 1.